# WritePrivateProfileString with int variable as value

Tags: variables, int

I'm quite new to C++. 
Right at the moment I'm trying to write and read an ini file. As I'm working with VS 2010 I d'like to use the WritePrivateProfileString function.

testwise it works like this

```
WritePrivateProfileString("testsection","testkey","testvalue","testfile.ini");
```

I can run this successfully.
My idea now is to hand overthe value within a variable of course which represents an int value.

```
WritePrivateProfileString("testsection","testkey",testvalue,"testfile.ini");
```

I understand that I would have to cast it first to LPCSTR or char so it works.

```
int testvalue =12;

WritePrivateProfileString("testsection","testkey",intToChar(testvalue),"testfile.ini");

//convert int to LPCSTR
char* intToChar(int temp){
char wert[8];
itoa(temp, wert, 10);
cout << wert;
return wert;
```

it does write to the file. but instead of a number i get random signs like  "<º-" and stuff.
I've been trying for an hour now. Using different convertion (to LPCSTR, to char, to string) without any success.

what am I doing wrong? I really stat to get desperate.

thanks for any hint.
    }

Answer (score 0):

WritePrivateProfileString function can handle only "string", not "Integer Value".

You can make string from integer using itoa().